# Combinations help please

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

What is the total combination I will have if I have 13 children and each kid has a choice to choose one of these 3 fruits a pears, grapes and orange(of which i have unlimited supply of each fruit)........what is the total the number different of combinations i can get

Please see the 3 different pictures(charts) i have added to display each child picking a fruit . i have uploaded three different examples which are 3 different combinations,in which 13 children can choose one of three fruit

but i have sent you three different combinations but i want to know what is the total amount of combinations i can have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsfCK.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZkF6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO9GZ.jpg)

Comment: Your question is unclear for many reasons.  If it is as simple as that you have an unlimited supply of each type of fruit and each child gets one fruit only., just apply multiplication principle.  You have three options for the fruit for the first child, then three options for the fruit for the second child and so on.  By multiplying the number of options for each you get a final total.  If this is *not* the intended interpretation, then you will need to do a much better job explaining the rules and what your "chart" with checkmarks is meant to represent.

Comment: Rephrased, if you ask for the number of functions from $\{kid1,kid2,kid3,\dots,kid13\}$ to $\{pear,grape,orange\}$, remember that the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ is conveniently notated as $B^A$ and the number of functions is $|B|^{|A|}$.

Comment: thanks for your and sorry my question is that clear but yes its you right i do have an unlimited amount of each fruit but each child only get to choose one and the chart is just an example but i added a picture of a chart to show one combination where the 13 kids have all chosen one fruit

Comment: to be honest im lost. Im not that great at math is there a way you could  explain it a bit more in layman's terms for me please or just tell me the total different number combination that i could have ? Sorry for being such a pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let refer to the [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), we have 3 choices for each kid thus the number of combinations is

$$3\cdot 3\cdot...\cdot 3= 3^{13}$$

and more in general for $k$ kids and $n$ fruits the number of combinations is

$$n^k$$

Comment: Thanks so the number of  total different combinations is 1594323 ?

Comment: Yes exactly http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E13

Comment: Wow thats a lot of different ways 13 people can choose but thanks for you help appreciate it

Comment: Combinations are often very counter intuitive and lead to very big numbers. For example the number of ways to arrange 5 people in a car with 5 seats is 5*4*3*2=120 which is not so intuitive at first